# Position fixed element is not apply max-width 100% of window's width

Tags: html, css

I have an element, of id "r-u-ok". It's a pop-up and its content can have different word counts.

I want to set only the max-width, not the fixed width. A fixed width can't self-adapt to the content's word count. Besides, I also hope to vertical align it in the middle and horizontal align it to the center.

But even when I set 100% to max-width attribute, its max-width still is not the width of window, though it contains many words.

WHY?

Ignore my poor English.

```css
#r-u-ok {
  position: fixed;
  /* display: none; */
  max-width: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="r-u-ok">
  I think it should 100% width of this window, if the word more enough.
</div>
```

Here is an example: [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Xheldon/jp88azbs/)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the pop-up to take 100% of the width ONLY if it has enough content?

Comment: Hey @XheldonCao ! I now doubt about your question, do you want  to set the width to 100% or do you want your `<div>` to adapt according to its content ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think due to the position fixed, the div cannot grow as it would in normal document flow.  To get over this, use an extra div - the outer div to position and the inner div can then grow with it's content:

```css
#r-u-ok {
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 99;
    text-align:center;
}
#r-u-ok > div {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="r-u-ok">
  <div>
  I think it should 100% width of this window, if the word more enough.
  </div>
</div>
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jp88azbs/7/)

Comment: Good one. This even works in IE, whereas mine doesn't.

Comment: yes...it's a good compatibility and awesome solution...and @MrLister has a other way if ignore the compatibility...thank you very mush! I love SO! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that with the `left:50%`, the system thinks you want to restrict the width to half of the window, even though you translate the whole thing by -50%.
So what you need to do is set the `width` explicitly. There is no other way. Otherwise you'd be stuck with this half.

Fortunately, `width: 100%` is not the only solution. What you can do is `width: max-content`, which does exactly what you need.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work in all browsers. IE and Edge will not comply. But most others will, if you provide the right prefixes.

```css
#r-u-ok {
  position: fixed;
  /* display: none; */
  max-width: 99%; /* changed */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  /* added */
  width:-webkit-max-content;
  width:-moz-max-content;
  width:max-content;
}
```

```html
<div id="r-u-ok">
  I think it should 100% width of this window, if the word more enough.
</div>
```

Comment: yes! that's what I wanted! hope the attribute "max-content" can be standardize...thanks!!!

Comment: Nice, didn't know about the `max-content` option

Answer (score 1):

Just add `width:100%`

```css
#r-u-ok {
  position: fixed;
  /* display: none; */
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
i have a demand, the element, which id is "r-u-ok",is a pop, has a several possibility of content's word count.it's judge by a ajax request's callback data. and i want the element only has a max-width, not a fixed width.a fixed width can't self-adaption
the content's word count, besides i also hope it is vertical align middle and horizontal align center. but, even i set 100% to max-width attribute, it's max-width still not the width of window, though it's contain many word. WHY?
<div id="r-u-ok">
  I think it should 100% width of this window, if the word more enough.
</div>
```

Comment: nope...div self-adaption it's content word is needed...anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to display this div in full width. In order to do that:

**Remove**

```
max-width: 70%;
```

**Add**

```
width: 100%;
```

**OR**

```
width: 100vw;
```

Comment: nope, i want the div self-adaption the content and has a max-width of window...anyway, thanks~